# Dynamic URL ReWriter not working

Tags: .htaccess, dynamic

I have created this Rule but its not working, what I need that if someone try to access, example.com/myinfo/city/location-names , he will be redirected to example.com/info/city/location-name.
I have already tried this,

```
RedirectMatch 301 http://www.example.com/myinfo/city/(.*) http://www.exampe.com/info/city/$1
```

am I doing something wrong

Comment: Use a relative URL and use the same domain: `RedirectMatch 301 /myinfo/city/(.*) http://www.example.com/info/city/$1`

Comment: Thank you So much, its working now